# Error while invoking API with DSS endpoint in WSO2 EI 6.6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am trying to invoke an API with a Dataservice endpoint. This is the in-sequence of the API.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="atms-v1-getATMInfo-in-sequence" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="SEQ_NAME" scope="default" type="STRING" value="atms_v1_getATMInfo_inSeq"/>
    <property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
    <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
    <log level="full"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint name="AtmInfoEndPoint">
            <address uri="https://127.0.0.1:8243/services/atmService"/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    </response>
</sequence>
```

But when I invoke the API, I am receiving an error as

```
[2020-09-17 07:22:58,565] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} - Error processing GET request for : /services/atmService/atms org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/atmService/atms and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:102)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:368)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:189)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I checked on a few documentation but couldn't find an answer. Please, someone, let me know how to fix this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Can you attach the data service configuration as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the soap action before calling the endpoint. The soap action should be the dataservice's operation name:

```
<property name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" value="urn:op_name"/>
```